# Not Getting Expected find results with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

Hi I am trying to get all questions on stackoverflow page

For this i am trying below code but nothing is getting printed is there anything i can rectify here ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

content = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/").content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")


for i in soup.find_all("a", class_="question-hyperlink", href=True):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using this to be able to get all links:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

content = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/").content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")

links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
print(links)
```

To be able to search by a class you should use this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

content = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/").content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")

links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', class_="question-hyperlink", href=True)]
print(links)
```

However after running the script i got a empty list printed what means it not found any link in the given class.

Comment: thanks for answering but it doesnt help  i require only questions to be printed so searching with class with your method all a tags are geting printed

Comment: I just edited my Answer. This should solve your issue ;)

Comment: but  if i try to inspect any question on STO i can  clearly see the class , text,href is present

Comment: that might be because the class you try to access is located within other classes or elements you then need to access first.